# Creating new variable using piping in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to create a new variable `confirmed_delta_perc` in a list of commands (piping) but am having an issue with the variable `active_delta` showing it is not found. I have confirmed it is in the data frame but is not being read. It also doesn't add the new variable.

```
COVID %>%
  select(county, confirmed, confirmed_delta) %>%
  mutate(confirmed_delta_perc = active_delta/active * 100) %>%
  filter(confirmed_delta_perc == 32)
```

Error:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `confirmed_delta_perc =
  active_delta/active`.
Caused by error:
! object 'active_delta' not found
```

This is the full list of directions to including in the pipe:
Using piping, create a link of commands that selects the county, confirmed, and confirmed_delta variables. Create a new variable called `confirmed_delta_perc` using the mutate() function. The values in this column should be the percentage of active delta cases of all active cases. Filter for all observation(s) that have a `confirmed_delta_perc` value of 32. Print out all observation(s).

I've tried modifing the `mutate()` by renaming the dataframe so it "redoes" it and adds the new variable but it doesn't work either.

There's not any observations that actually equal 32 but it still should add the variable but is not.

Does anyone have any ideas?

````
dput(head(COVID))

structure(list(county = c("Washington", "Fountain", "Jay", "Wabash", 
"Fayette", "Washington"), confirmed = c(620L, 737L, 930L, 1530L, 
1336L, 675L), confirmed_delta = c(18L, 12L, 11L, 49L, 19L, 29L
), deaths = c(5L, 8L, 14L, 25L, 33L, 6L), deaths_delta = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), recovered = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), recovered_delta = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), active = c(615L, 729L, 918L, 1512L, 1305L, 
669L), active_delta = c(18L, 11L, 11L, 49L, 19L, 28L), active_delta_perc = c(0.0292682926829268, 
0.0150891632373114, 0.0119825708061002, 0.0324074074074074, 0.0145593869731801, 
0.0418535127055306)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")```
````

Comment: `COVID %>% select(county, confirmed, confirmed_delta)` extracts just the three named columns from `COVID`, so `active_delta` is not available to subsequent parts of the chain. Your `mutate` step is trying to use variables called `active_delta` and `active` which do not exist at that step. If those variables exist in `COVID`, you either need to add those variables into the `select()` step or remove the `select` step altogether.

Comment: So I've tried adding the two variables `active_delta` and `active` and it will run without error but it doesn't add the new variable to the COVID dataframe. This is the output: ```[1] county               confirmed            confirmed_delta     
[4] active_delta         active               confirmed_delta_perc
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)```

Comment: It will be easier to help if you can make your question reproducible. Can you add the output of `dput(head(COVID))` to your question? This will create a code recipe for others to have a dataframe called `COVID` that has the same data format as yours (but just the first few rows).

Comment: I suspect the code of the first three steps is running fine, and perhaps you do have a row that is close to 32%, e.g. like if you had 29 active_delta / 90 active = 0.32222... Your filter column is looking for values of "32" but in this case the number you might actually want is something that is close to (but not exactly equal to) 32. So perhaps something like `filter(abs(confirmed_delta_perc-32) < 1)` would be more appropriate.

Comment: What is the abs function?

Comment: absolute value, so we could specify anything from -0.5 to 0.5 by saying `abs(x) < 0.5` as a shortcut for `x > -0.5 & x < 0.5`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For most numbers of cases, it is impossible for any portion of them to be *exactly* 32%. For instance what we would report 29 of 90 cases as "32%" but that's really 32.222222 which is not strictly equal to 32. So you will need to specify what range around 32 counts as a match. Here, I say anything within 0.5 of 32 on either side, from 31.5 to 32.5, is close enough.

```
COVID <- COVID %>%
  mutate(confirmed_delta_perc = active_delta/active * 100) %>%
  filter(abs(confirmed_delta_perc - 32) <= 0.5)
```

Comment: None of them are actually anywhere near 32. most are 0.0... I was told there are none that actually equal 32 but the issue is now the `mutate()` is not actually adding the variable `confirmed_delta_perc` as specified in the pipe

Comment: The pipe doesn't change the objects it's acting on unless you assign the output of the pipe to the original data. So `COVID %>% mutate(new_col = 1)` will print out the new column but won't change COVID itself. You'd need `COVID <- COVID %>% mutate(new_col = 1)` for COVID itself to be altered.

Comment: Gotcha - that did work. I think the question from the assignment may be wrong then - or at least not as they expected. Thank you! I've only been working with R for a week.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
COVID <- COVID %>%
  mutate(confirmed_delta_perc = active_delta/active * 100) %>%
  filter( round(confirmed_delta_perc, 0) == 32)
```

filtering by `abs` function as suggested by @JonSpring in the comments is better though